# is there a way to normalize vectors with different input size with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

The following function tries to normalize 3D vectors

```
def my_norm(v):
    """
    @type v: Nx3 numpy array
    """
    return v / numpy.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)[:, None]
```

It works when N > 1. For N=1, I got `ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds`. I can do the following check to deal with both cases, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way?

```
def my_norm(v):
    """
    @type v: Nx3 numpy array
    """
    if len(v) == 1:
        return v / numpy.linalg.norm(v)
    return v / numpy.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)[:, None]
```

Comment: The first solution should work for 1X3 array, the error suggests you may be passing a (3,) array instead of (1,3).

Comment: @Psidom You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axis=-1` and keep the dimensions with `keepdims=True` -

```
v/np.linalg.norm(v, axis=-1,keepdims=True)
```

**Sample runs**

1D Case :

```
In [61]: v = np.random.rand(6)

In [62]: v/np.linalg.norm(v)
Out[62]: array([ 0.22,  0.1 ,  0.28,  0.58,  0.64,  0.33])

In [63]: v/np.linalg.norm(v, axis=-1,keepdims=True)
Out[63]: array([ 0.22,  0.1 ,  0.28,  0.58,  0.64,  0.33])
```

2D Case :

```
In [58]: v = np.random.rand(4,6)

In [59]: v / np.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)[:, None]
Out[59]: 
array([[ 0.53,  0.04,  0.38,  0.21,  0.58,  0.43],
       [ 0.49,  0.4 ,  0.02,  0.56,  0.38,  0.38],
       [ 0.05,  0.49,  0.45,  0.18,  0.54,  0.47],
       [ 0.45,  0.61,  0.19,  0.1 ,  0.14,  0.61]])

In [60]: v/np.linalg.norm(v, axis=-1,keepdims=True)
Out[60]: 
array([[ 0.53,  0.04,  0.38,  0.21,  0.58,  0.43],
       [ 0.49,  0.4 ,  0.02,  0.56,  0.38,  0.38],
       [ 0.05,  0.49,  0.45,  0.18,  0.54,  0.47],
       [ 0.45,  0.61,  0.19,  0.1 ,  0.14,  0.61]])
```